# Where is memory allocated for instances and the values of variables in Java?

Tags: java, class, object, static, heap-memory

When we instantiate a class where is that stored? and where does the values inside the object are stored.

example:

`MyDemoClass obj1 = new MyDemoClass();`

where is obj1 stored??

and if I do

`obj1.x = 10;`

Where is the x stored?

where is this 10 stored?

And if we make variable x static

```
class MyDemoClass {
    static int x;
    MyDemoClass() {
        x = 10;
    }
}
```

Now where is x stored and where is value 10 stored?

Can someone explain it in simple words?

Thank You for taking your time for this newbie doubt!

Comment: Read here https://www.baeldung.com/java-stack-heap, and don't worry (for now) about the memory with Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyDemoClass obj1 = new MyDemoClass();

> where is obj1 stored??

```
obj1 is just a label/pointer. In memory it will be assigned to the stack. The object that obj1 points to will be on the heap (all objects in Java exist on the heap)
```

> and if I do

> obj1.x = 10;

> Where is the x stored?

```
x is stored on the heap with the object
```

> And if we make variable x static where is this 10 stored?

```
x is then stored on the heap, associated with the MyDemoClass Class object
```

Comment: `obj1 is just a label/pointer.`
is obj1 called 'reference variable'  pointing to actual 'object' which is in heap??

`x is stored on the heap with the object`
where is the value 10 stored then?? 

Thanks for answering 
I have a better understanding now than before.

Comment: @defaultacc "is obj1 called reference variable..." I don't know - that's just nomenclature. What I can tell you is that when you compile Java into a .class file, the label 'obj' is replaced by its position in the stack frame.

Comment: @defaultacc "where is the value 10 stored then??" Calling `new MyDemoClass();` will allocate space for x (within the object) on the heap